# disable enter key in textarea on jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, textarea

I want to disable enter key in textarea on jsp but the function is not working and enter key still make new line when I press it.

Below is the function to disable enter key in textarea :

```
$("textarea").on("keypress", function(e) {
if ((e.keyCode == 13)) {
e.preventDefault();

    }
});
```

And there is the jsp :

```
<td><form:textarea path="connote.shipperAddr" id="shipperAddr" name="shipperAddr" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" onblur="whenEmpty(this);"
htmlEscape="true" 
rows="3" cols="34"
tabindex="5"/> <form:errors
path="connote.shipperAddr" cssClass="error" /></td>
```

How can I disable enter key from a textarea?

Comment: But it still not working

Comment: What's the order of Form and Script in the JSP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oqq8rr2x/)

```
$("textarea").on("keypress", function(e) {
if ((e.keyCode == 13)) {
e.preventDefault();

    }
});
```

Please make sure your selector `$(textarea)` is able to get the textarea element.Is `form:textarea` rendered as normal `<textarea></textarea>`.

Comment: But I can't change the element because the element binds with the other function.

Comment: Try using the id _"shipperAddr"_ as selector. Eg: `$("#shipperAddr")`.
And also make sure you register this event as soon as page loads by including your script in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: yeah that's work hahaha, thanks Mr. Drizzt :D